# Kannel DLR Queue Timeout

Tags: sms, kannel

Using Kannel w/ internal storage for SMPP (not using mySQL) I sometimes don't get DLR's back from some carriers, any way I can just time them out after a day w/out manually suspending & then flushing the DLR queue?

(dlr_mask is set properly, i just don't get em all and it slows down once it gets big enough)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try defining the validityperiod in the group smsc. After that there is expiry time with every SMSC, some expire after 4 hours and some after 48 hours.